# How to convert price string into float?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Set-up**

I'm migrating my WooCommerce shops to Shopify.

I'm using a Shopify app that creates a product grid. The app uses Javascript; I'm totally new to Javascript.

On the product grid, `<span v-if="hasDiscount" v-html="displayLongDiscountedPrice"></span>` displays the product's discounted price, e.g. `€966,79`.

I think `v-html` implies Vue.js, but I'm not totally sure. Nor am I sure if what I'm about to ask should be done the way I think it should, or that I should use this Vue framework.

---

**Question**

I need to manipulate each product's discounted price. For example, multiply it by 6.

To do so, I need to convert the product price from a string to an integer. How do I do this?

---

**Code tries**

```
var number = parseFloat(`<span v-if="hasDiscount" v-html="displayLongDiscountedPrice"></span>`);
var number = parseFloat(`<span v-if="hasDiscount" v-html="displayLongDiscountedPrice"></span>`.replace("€", "").replace(",", "."));
var number = paserInt(`<span v-if="hasDiscount" v-html="displayLongDiscountedPrice"></span>`);
```

All yield `NaN`.

Comment: Yeah you're dealing with vue here. I'm no expert, but you almost certainly don't want to be attempting the conversion at the templating level (as you're doing above). You need to find the JavaScript code for the view associated with the above template and (maybe) convert the `displayLongDiscountedPrice` value there. There's probably already some formatting going on to apply the currency symbol etc. If the raw (unformatted) value is communicated as a string, you can convert it to float for multiplication with `parseFloat`.

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. I'll ask the developer of the app; I think `displayLongDiscountedPrice` is defined on their server – it's being called in their code and not defined anywhere as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript code to convert your string into a decimal:

```
var s = "€966,79";
var d = s.substr(1).replace(",", ".") * 1;
```

It's a bit hackish but it works in a pinch.  The `substr` removes the monetary symbol, the `replace` changes the comma to a period, and the `* 1` converts it from string to decimal.  From there you can multiply it by six with `var x = d * 6`.

Edit:  you can also do `d = parseFloat(s.substr(1).replace(",", "."))`.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for thinking with me, but this still yields a `Nan`. Think yours is a more elegant version of my 2nd try.